# Measure-Object -Average round to two decimal places

Tags: powershell, average

This may be as simple as separating out the statement to not use multiple pipes, however, I have the following code which inputs a text file with a varying (usually ~800) lines of digits ranging from 0.0 to 11.0 or more.  Using Powershell, I want to take all of those values and average them, rounding to two decimal places.  Below is the code attempting to use `Measure-Object -Average`, but I know this is not the best choice as it outputs information including Count, Max, and Min, whereas all I want is the average with no other txt.

```
Get-Content C:\daily_values_uv_temp2_non_avg.txt | Measure-Object -Average | Out-File C:\daily_values_uv.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns strings. If you want to calculate an average of numbers you would need to convert it first ... something like this:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\daily_values_uv_temp2_non_avg.txt |
    ForEach-Object{[float]$_} |
        Measure-Object -Average |
            Select-Object -Property Average -OutVariable result
[MATH]::Round($result.average,2)
```

To get the result rounded to two decimal points you can use the `Round()` method of the `[MATH]` class.

Mathias is right ... I didn't know that. Thanks.

So you actually just need to add the `Select-Object` to select the property you're after.

```
Get-Content C:\daily_values_uv_temp2_non_avg.txt | 
    Measure-Object -Average | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average |
            Out-File C:\daily_values_uv.txt
```

Comment: `Measure-Object` coerces the input value to `[double]` if `-Sum` and/or `-Average` is specified, `ForEach-Object{[float]$_} |` is unnecessary here

Comment: My pleasure! :-D

Comment: Hi @olaf how do I intergrate `[MATH]::Round($result.average,2)` into your updated solution?  Right now the code is giving me 1.5743176 ect, not rounding it to 1.57

Comment: To update, I was able to get the desired result by using your edit above, then setting `$result = Get-Content C:aily_values_uv.txt' and then using `[MATH]::Round($result,2)`.  However, that's probably not the fastest way to do it or what you intended...

Comment: I just created a small file with sample input data and it worked without the need for the `.round()` method. Why do you think it's not the fastest way? Do you really need the fastest way? How long did it take? How many data do you have in your inout file?

Comment: Well, it seemed like your example was more streamlined.  My input file has around 800 lines currently.  It'll have a line for every minute of the day where the sun is up.  I don't know why, but it still gives 0 as the average, unless I add the line I showed above.  As long as it works, I guess I should take it for what it is.